# How to perform API test for windows desktop applications (WPF)?

Tags: windows, api, testing, desktop

I am a complete beginner working as a tester, I have found multiple resources in google about web APIs and its HTTP methods (GET,PUT,POST,DELETE). However I am confused **what is the equivalent of these 'HTTP methods' for a windows desktop application?** **How do one actually perform a Windows application API test?** I have no experience testing windows application APIs and would like to understand it first before making any test plans.